# How to SUM the Alias Field Columns In MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sum

How to SUM the Alias Filed Column(Repeat_Customer) ?

```
SELECT CustomerID,COUNT(CustomerID) AS Repeat_Customer 
FROM Purchase_Details
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 1;
```

Comment: if you need the sum then why you need the count ? do you need both sum and count ?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a subquery.

```
SELECT SUM(Repeat_Customer) AS total_repeats
FROM (
    SELECT CustomerID,COUNT(CustomerID) AS Repeat_Customer 
    FROM Purchase_Details
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) > 1
) AS subquery
```